# Genebank files manipulation with bash

Tags: bash

I have this genebank [file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/JF801956.1). And I need your help in manipulating it

Iam picking a random part of the file

```
CDS             complement(1750..1956)
                     /gene="MAMA_L4"
                     /note="similar to MIMI_L9"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="AEQ60146.1"
                     /translation="MHFLDDDNDESNNCFDDKEKARDKIIIDMLNLIIGKKKTSYKCL
                     DYILSEQEYKFAILSIVENSIFLF"
     misc_feature    complement(2020..2235)
                     /note="MAMA_L5; similar to replication origin binding
                     protein (fragment)"
     gene            complement(2461..2718)
                     /gene="MAMA_L6"
     CDS             complement(2461..2718)
                     /gene="MAMA_L6"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /product="T5orf172 domain-containing protein"
                     /protein_id="AEQ60147.1"
                     /translation="MSNNLAFYIITTNYHQSQNIYKIGIHTGNPYDLITRYITYFPDV
                     IITYFQYTDKAKKVESDLKEKLSKCRITNIKGNLSEWIVID"
```

My target is to "extract" the info of  /translation= and /product= like following

T5orf172 domain-containing protein
MSNNLAFYIITTNYHQSQNIYKIGIHTGNPYDLITRYITYFPDV**IITYFQYTDKAKKVESDLKEKLSKCRITNIKGNLSEWIVID**

*with bold I highlighted the issue that I had.

I am trying to write a bash script so I was thinking to apply something like:

```
grep -w /product= genebank.file  |cut -d= -f2| sed 's/"//'g  > File1

grep -w /translation= genebank.file  |cut -d= -f2| sed 's/"//'g  > File2  

paste  File1 File2
```

T the problem is that in the translation entries when I use grep I got only the first line. So it prints until the bold line like
T5orf172 domain-containing protein  MSNNLAFYIITTNYHQSQNIYKIGIHTGNPYDLITRYITYFPDV

Can anybody help me to step over this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -En '/^\s*\/(product|translation)="/{
    s///
    :a
    /"$/! { N; s/\n\s*//; ba; }
    s/"$//p
    }' file |
sed 'N; s/\n/\t/'
```

Note: This assumes the second occurrence of the delimiter `"` is immediately followed by a newline in the input file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Its  99% close to what I was looking for, maybe my desired output wasn't so clear but I want to have the product next to translation ( that's why I used the paste). I tried to edit your command { N; s/\n\s*//; ba; } to { N; s/\t\s*//; ba; } but still I could able to do obtain what I want. Is it possible to edit it in the way to obtain the product next to the translation?

Comment: @KGee If I understand you correctly, the easiest way is to create a pipeline by appending a second `sed` in order to "paste" two consecutive lines. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this but if you add -A1 to your grep command you'll get one line after the match.

```
grep -w /product= genebank.file  |cut -d= -f2| sed 's/"//'g  > File1
grep -A1 -w /translation= genebank.file  |cut -d= -f2| sed 's/^ *//g' > File2
paste  File1 File2
```

You would need to delete that extra newline but that should get you close.

Comment: First of all,  I would like to thank you for your answer. The -A1 works but not properly. I mean by properly that Genebank files contain multiple lines (usually between 1 -10 ) after the line exists the "/translation=" so it difficult to target in the next line. Unfortunately, the format of Genefile is really weird and it is hard to manipulate them. I was thinking "EXTRACT THE TEXT BETWEEN THE DOUBLE QUOTES " after the grep but I have no idea how to do it.